# Facebook like button for contest. Risk for fraud?

Tags: html, facebook-like

I'm hosting a photo contest and I'm planning to use the Facebook like button for public voting. Every contest entrant will get their own page with their own individual like button.

I will then use this amount of likes every entrant gets in order to get the winner of the contest.

My question is if their is any (big) risk of fraud in using this method?

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&width=450&layout=standard&action=like&size=small&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80&appId=1738096699615417" width="450" height="80" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Buttons are tied to one Facebook account, so it is relatively safe.

But:

- People can create more than one account
- People can "buy" likes on some platforms. There are "click farms" for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_farm

Both are not allowed, of course.